# Integrate and debug a typescript project with existing PHP application hosted on local Apache server

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm new to the javascript world, I have no experience with typescript, node.js etc I'm more accustomed to OOP languages like Java.

I'm developing a web application with PHP (locally hosted on an Apache server) that generates HTML server-side with a template engine , then I use   javascript to do client-side operations like dynamically adding buttons on clicks, ajax requests, parse dynamically generated forms to build a json request body and so on.

I quickly realized that developing complex components with javascript is quite messy, a single file with all the classes, all the functions, no type checking, and now a single component is already 500 lines of codes, with the potential to grow more (also, I have to make more of these on various pages).

Debugging a massive and complex single file is already becoming a daunting task.
I could split the file into many pieces, but then I have to manually import them with multiple <script src tags but this is out of question.

I did some research and tought I did find a solution with typescript and once more it is not that easy: one has to compile the .ts into a .js then bundle the .js with browserify (or similar) that,once again, makes a massive javascript with all the classes and functions. I did some further research and realized that's simply how javascript works.

So I am back with the same problems, since the browser can't interpret node js functions, I'm back to debugging a massive and complex javascript, but with the extra overhead of compiling and bundling to deploy new changes.

I'm sorry for the non technical and broad question (it's more of a rant I know) but having spent tens of hours researching, I can't find a way to create a sane development environment for my javascript components.

To summarize, the main problems I need to address are:

1. how to create a javascript development environment that resembles an
   OOP language like Java (classes, libraries, packages etc)
2. a sane debugging tool that integrates with the browser and makes me place breakpoints on .ts files and not the bundled js.

About number 2, I have already tried Visual Studio Code. I successfully ran the debugger with a compiled js file(that of course didn't work in the browser because of require() ), but I can't find a way to make it work with a bundled js.

Sorry for the long post, thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the issue with .ts files? Are you uncomfortable when debugging them, or it's just because it's still a huge .ts file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [javascript modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) to organize your packages.

If you need compatibility with legacy browsers or additional functionality (e.g. transpiling typescript to javascript), build with a bundler like [parcel](https://parceljs.org/) or [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or [rollup](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/) or [browserify](http://browserify.org/) and enable [source maps](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#outputsourcemap).

[Source maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Use_a_source_map) allow dev tools to map the bundled js back to its original source file, so you can set breakpoints and such.

There’s an [extension for vscode](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug) for connecting the debugger to the browser.

Most (all?) bundlers can be set up to [watch for changes](https://parceljs.org/cli.html#serve) and recompile automatically, so during development you don't have to manually rerun the bundling every time you make a change. Just edit your file, save, and reload in the browser.

Comment: thanks, looks like I was almost there. I was missing the source maps for bundled js and the watcher for files changes.